# python: convert 2 dimension list of string to float

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimension list of type string I'm trying to convert it to int. Things I've tried so far:

```
[[float(i) for i in lst[j] for j in lst]
```

with a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
         lst[i][j]=float(lst[i][j])
```

Comment: Two things stand out: your list comprehension has unbalanced `]`, so it will error out. and you are trying to convert to `float`, but your question says `int`?

Comment: What's the problem you are having? The `for` loop solution works

Comment: In the first solution, the order of loops are incorrect. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> nums = [['4.58416458379', '3.40522046551', '1.68991195077'], ['3.61503670628', '5.64553650642', '1.39648965337'], ['8.02595866276', '8.42455003038', '7.93340754534']]
>>> [[float(y) for y in x] for x in nums]
[[4.58416458379, 3.40522046551, 1.68991195077], [3.61503670628, 5.64553650642, 1.39648965337], [8.02595866276, 8.42455003038, 7.93340754534]]
```

I'm not sure what your intention is but since you claim the `for` loop version didn't work, maybe you want a one dimensional result, in that case:

```
>>> [float(y) for x in nums for y in x]
[4.58416458379, 3.40522046551, 1.68991195077, 3.61503670628, 5.64553650642, 1.39648965337, 8.02595866276, 8.42455003038, 7.93340754534]
```

Comment: This should be wrapped in a `try/except`, for those strings that cannot be converted to float. If not, at least a check to make sure you don't pass in empty strings.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks but I'll leave that as a comment, OP can chose to do that if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your solutions are close to working. Indeed, the second one should work already, though it can perhaps be improved a little bit.

Here's how I'd update the list comprehension version. The (perhaps dubious) advantage of this version is that it creates a new nested list containing floats, and leaves the original nested list of strings unchanged (so you can use it for something else, if you need to):

```
new_lst = [[float(string) for string in inner] for inner in lst]
```

Here's how I'd update your for loop code. Unlike the version using a list comprehension, this code modifies the contents of the original list of lists in place. While your current code should work just fine, the version below is somewhat more "pythonic" in my opinion, since it iterates over the contents of the list, rather than iterating over ranges and indexing the lists. Indexing is only needed for the assignment, and we get the index along with the string using the `enumerate` built-in function:

```
for inner in lst:
    for index, string in enumerate(inner):
        inner[index] = float(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map()`, here's a simplified example

```
nums = [['4.58416458379','1.68991195077'], ['8.02595866276'],
    ['3.61503670628', '5.64553650642', '1.39648965337']]

def myFloat(myList):
    return map(float, myList)

map(myFloat, nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newList = []
listSize = len(oldList)
for i in range(0, listSize):
    newList.append([])
    for j in range(0, 2):
        newList[i].append(float(oldData[i][j]))
```

This helped me, this makes a new list called **newList** and type casts all the elements from **oldList** into **newList**. Although **newList** is initialised a 1-dimensional array, line 4 adds new dimensions according to whatever dimension your to be converted array is.

Comment: please add some explanation while answering question. "This helped me

" should be replaced.

Answer (score -2):

correct your first solution to:

```
>>> sss = [['4.584','1.689'],['8.025'],['3.615','5.645','1.396']]
>>> fff = [float(s) for ss in sss for s in ss]      #notice the order of loops
>>> fff
[4.584, 1.689, 8.025, 3.615, 5.645, 1.396]
```

it works.